# Painting a UniformGrid in C# using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I am relatively new to C# and I'm trying to create a window with a grid of a dynamic amount of same-sized squares. The squares are then to have their color changed by a process.

I'm currently struggling to generate the grid of squares. Whenever I run the application it seems to be going crazy on resources and I'm not sure why.

The code I am using follows:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {


    //create a blue brush
    SolidColorBrush vBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue); 

    //set the columns and rows to 100
    cellularGrid.Columns = mCellAutomaton.GAME_COLUMNS; 
    cellularGrid.Rows = mCellAutomaton.GAME_ROWS;

    //change the background of the cellular grid to yellow
    cellularGrid.Background = Brushes.Yellow;

    //create 100*100 blue rectangles to fill the cellular grid
    for (int i = 0; i < mCellAutomaton.GAME_COLUMNS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mCellAutomaton.GAME_ROWS; j++) {

            Rectangle vRectangle = new Rectangle();

            vRectangle.Width = 10;
            vRectangle.Height = 10;
            vRectangle.Fill = vBrush;

            cellularGrid.Children.Add(vRectangle);


        }
    }
}
```

Is this even the approach I want to take if I want a modifiable grid of squares?

Thanks for any help,

Jason

Comment: Why not use the WPF uniform grid?

Comment: 100*100 = 10000 GDI handles in one go, no wonder this is getting busy =)

Comment: @SebastianEdelmeier GDI!?!?! this is WPF not crappy winforms.

Comment: @HighCore: Mea culpa, I meant handles, without GDI.

Comment: @xyzjace: 1 - What's this for? I don't see the point of creating 10000 little blue squares on screen. 2 - sa_ddam213's solution works fine. The problem is not UI Elements, is your nested `for`s. 3 - What's the point of defining a supposedly "dynamic" sized Uniform Grid and then setting the rectangle sizes to 10 x 10. Also if you need the grid cells to be 10 x 10 sized, size the grid not the contained rectangles.

Comment: @SebastianEdelmeier WPF objects are not HWND based. There's no such thing as a handle in WPF. Do your homework.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 It does actually use a UniformGrid, the grid is defined in the XAML. 

HighCore: It's the beginning of a Morphogenetic Cell Simulator. The amount of 'squares' represent cells, and change color based on their state, defined by a set of rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to perform pretty fast

```
   <Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="350" Name="UI">
        <Grid Name="Test">
            <UniformGrid Name="UniGrid" />
        </Grid>
    </Window>


/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddRows(new Size(10, 10));
    }

    private void AddRows(Size recSize)
    {
        UniGrid.Columns = (int)(UniGrid.ActualWidth / recSize.Width);
        UniGrid.Rows = (int)(UniGrid.ActualHeight / recSize.Height);
        for (int i = 0; i < UniGrid.Columns * UniGrid.Rows; i++)
        {
            UniGrid.Children.Add(new Rectangle { Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow), Margin = new Thickness(1) });
        }
    }
}
```